# Lucene indexes not persisting in Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I have an @Indexed entity on which I perform Hibernate Search. I am following the steps as follows:

1. Persist entity via Hibernate.
2. Search using Hibernate Search. (it works)

But, as soon as i restart my application server. I am not able to search on the recently persisted entity. I am unable to understand what's happening here. I think my lucene indexes are getting generated but not persisted.

Any help in the right direction would be of great help.

Comment: When you say "I am not able to search", you mean that queries don't return any result, right? Not that they return only null values, or that an exception of some kind is thrown? And I assume there aren't any errors in logs, either?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you configured your directory provider correctly:

1. `hibernate.search.default.directory_provider` should be either not set at all or set to `filesystem`. `local-heap` (formerly `ram`) means not persistent, and in any case should not be used in production unless you really know what you're doing.
2. `hibernate.search.default.indexBase` should be set to the path of a directory on your filesystem. The default is the current working directory, I think, and if you start your app from two different directories it will be as if the index was lost.

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_configuration

Comment: `hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem`
`hibernate.search.default.indexBase=D:\\Tool\\indexes` I am using these configuration values. Directory is being created at application start and modified date also updates whenever i persist a value. But, indexes are not being listed when checked through Luke.

Comment: @gschambial And you don't have per-index settings? Like `hibernate.search.MyIndexName.directory_provider`?

Comment: No, I have global settings for all indexes.

Comment: Exactly! But, i guess there is some other issue. I have got some lead. Recently, i added JUnit test cases in which i created an in memory datasource and now this datasource is overriding my original datasource, idk why. I am looking into it. I guess it's not an issue with hibernate search but some configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need reindex your entities if you have a temporal path.

This is an example with SpringBoot:

```
 @Component
public class BuildSearchIndex
        implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * Create an initial Lucene index for the data already present in the
     * database.
     * This method is called when Spring's startup.
     */
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {


        try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
                    Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "An error occurred trying to build the serach index: " +
                            e.toString());
        }
        return;
    }


}
```